# How to get Youtube video results in Java?

Tags: java, python

I want to convert the below Python code which searches for Youtube videos, into Java.

```py
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : input()})
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
print(search_results)
print("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852)

Comment: Can you update your question with what you have tried up to! and please let know to the user what kind of piece of code it is and where did you get from?

Comment: I'm trying to get youtube videos href by asking user input.I want search results of youtube videos.

Comment: Yes, That is a good thing you are doing something meaningful work. Here My concern is [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is all about solving problems when you stuck somewhere not to learn them how to convert code. So Have you tried so far to write java code? If yes then please update in the question as well. And In next question update please provide the detail of code that where did you get from?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the Youtube API:[Search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). This API allows you to add Youtube features and functionality in your application. On the right side of the page there is a section to try a sample request ("Try this API" section). On the bottom of the page there is a "SHOW CODE" button which allows you to get the relevant code in many different programming languages. One of the offered languages is Java.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
public class IamJava {

    private static final String AM_I_JAVA_OR_PYTHON = "amIJavaOrPython.py";

    private static final String I_AM_PYTHON = "import urllib.request\n" + "import urllib.parse\n" + "import re\n" + "\n"
            + "query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({\"search_query\" : input()})\n"
            + "html_content = urllib.request.urlopen(\"http://www.youtube.com/results?\" + query_string)\n"
            + "search_results = re.findall(r'href=\\\"\\/watch\\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())\n"
            + "print(search_results)\n" + "print(\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\" + search_results[0])\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(AM_I_JAVA_OR_PYTHON));
            out.write(I_AM_PYTHON);
            out.close();

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", AM_I_JAVA_OR_PYTHON);
            Process p = pb.start();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Ooops from Java!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy and welcome to [StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions#10812)!